# Migrate from DateField to DateTimeField in Django

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration

I have a model with field

```
date = models.DateField()
```

Now I want to migrate this field to DateTimeField, so it should look like this:

```
date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I know that I should run the commands below to make migrations.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I tried to use this command `python manage.py schemamigration --auto appname` but it's not help me

But I want to migrate all of this field with saving the date and only add the time 00:00:00:000000.
Could you help me to explain how can I do it?

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my issue, so below I add steps that helped to do this migration.

Change the type of your field in models.py from `DateField()` to `DateTimeField()`
Run command below

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

And know you will have field type in the database as `DateTimeField()` but in column `date`, we will see only date like '2020-09-23'.
So to change the format as '2020-09-23 00:00:00' I run my SQLite database and in ExecuteSQL view run the below command.

```
UPDATE table_name SET date=DATETIME(date, '0 minutes');
```

I am not sure if this solution is best practice, but it works for me.

**EDIT:**

The above solution work, but want to present the second possibility.

> First

Add a new field in Model, which will be the same as expected after changes `date`

```
new_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

> Second

After that, let's do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

> Third

Now, we have to columns with dates, so we can copy values from `date` to `new_date`.To do it we have to create new migration as below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name --empty
```

This command will create a new migration

> Fourth

Now we have to modify file as below (let's suppose, that we modify `User` model)

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from datetime import datetime

def set_my_defaults(apps, schema_editor):

        User = apps.get_model('app_name', 'user')
        for us in User.objects.all():
            old = pr.date
            old_date = datetime(old.year, old.month, old.day, 10, 1, 1, 1)

            us.new_date = old_date
            us.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('appname', 'previous_migration_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_my_defaults),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='user',
            name='date',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='user',
            old_name='new_date',
            new_name='date',
        ),
    ]
```

As you can see, firstly we copy values from `date` column to `new_date` as datetime. After that, remove `date` column and change name from `new_date` to `date`