# Migrating back from DateTimeField to DateField in Django

Tags: django

I have a Django Model with two DateTimeFields:

```
class FacilityTender(models.Model):
    """
    Class to store Facility Tender
    """
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('company.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
 ...
```

I now have to change the DateTimeFields to DateFields. Doing so, the app can't be deployed since when querying the objects created before the migration don't fit to the new DateField.

There is no error coming up when running the migration itself.

It returns:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'31 11:41:29'

for this qs: running_tenders = FacilityTender.objects.filter(publisher__cashpool__name=user_cashpool.name)
```

Full Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/facilities

Django Version: 3.2.9
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'applications.bank',
 'applications.cashpool',
 'applications.company',
 'applications.core',
 'applications.dashboard',
 'applications.universe',
 'applications.user']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/applications/dashboard/templates/dashboard/dashboard_frame.html, error at line 0
   invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'31 11:41:29'
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : {% load static %}
   4 : 
   5 :     <head>
   6 : 
   7 :         <!-- Meta -->
   8 :         <meta charset="UTF-8">
   9 :         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   10 : 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/applications/dashboard/views.py", line 297, in render_facilities
    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard_facilities.html', context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jonas/PycharmProjects/Finchin/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 64, in convert_date
    return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))

Exception Type: ValueError at /dashboard/facilities
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'31 11:41:29'
```

```
# migration

# Generated by Django 3.2.9 on 2021-12-01 12:05

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('company', '0031_auto_20211201_1200'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='company',
            name='pseudo',
            field=models.CharField(default='258404676f4bd1320a3e48c4', max_length=50),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='facilitytender',
            name='end_date',
            field=models.DateField(),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='facilitytender',
            name='start_date',
            field=models.DateField(),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate from DateField to DateTimeField in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64024229/migrate-from-datefield-to-datetimefield-in-django)

Comment: Sounds like you would need to patch your migration script. Can you post the migration code as it was generated?